# Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, list, split, turtle-graphics

I am trying read a file and split a cell in each line by a comma and then display only the first and the second cells which contain information regarding the latitude and the longitude.
This is the file:

```
time,latitude,longitude,type
2015-03-20T10:20:35.890Z,38.8221664,-122.7649994,earthquake
2015-03-20T10:18:13.070Z,33.2073333,-116.6891667,earthquake
2015-03-20T10:15:09.000Z,62.242,-150.8769,earthquake
```

My program:

```py
def getQuakeData():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
    readfile = open(filename, "r")
    readlines = readfile.readlines()

    Type = readlines.split(",")
    x = Type[1]
    y = Type[2]
    for points in Type:
        print(x,y)
getQuakeData()
```

When I try to execute this program, it gives me an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Please help me!

Comment: Because `list` has no `split()` only `string` objects have `split`

Comment: `readlines()` returns a `list`. You have to use `split()` on each string in that `list`.

Comment: Read the error closely. You are trying split `readlines`, which is a list. That cannot be done.

Comment: Why are you using `readlines` in the first place? If you just want the first line as one string, that's `readline`. If you want the whole file as one giant string, that's `read`. If you want a list or other iterable of lines, you _can_ use `readlines` for that, but you can also just use the file itself, so it's still not useful.

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider using the `csv` module here. Especially if there's actually a header line; then you could use `for row in csv.DictReader(readfile):` and then your values are `row['latitude']` and `row['longitude']` instead of `row[1]` and `row[2]`, which might be more readable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you've actually got a wider confusion here.

The initial error is that you're trying to call `split` on the whole list of lines, and you can't `split` a list of strings, only a string. So, you need to `split` *each line*, not the whole thing.

And then you're doing `for points in Type`, and expecting each such `points` to give you a new `x` and `y`. But that isn't going to happen. `Types` is just two values, `x` and `y`, so first `points` will be `x`, and then points will be `y`, and then you'll be done. So, again, you need to loop over each line and get the `x` and `y` values from *each line*, not loop over a single `Types` from a single line.

So, everything has to go inside a loop over every line in the file, and do the `split` into `x` and `y` once for each line. Like this:

```
def getQuakeData():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
    readfile = open(filename, "r")

    for line in readfile:
        Type = line.split(",")
        x = Type[1]
        y = Type[2]
        print(x,y)

getQuakeData()
```

As a side note, you really should `close` the file, ideally with a `with` statement, but I'll get to that at the end.

---

Interestingly, the problem here isn't that you're being too much of a newbie, but that you're trying to solve the problem in the same abstract way an expert would, and just don't know the details yet. This is completely doable; you just have to be explicit about mapping the functionality, rather than just doing it implicitly. Something like this:

```
def getQuakeData():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
    readfile = open(filename, "r")
    readlines = readfile.readlines()
    Types = [line.split(",") for line in readlines]
    xs = [Type[1] for Type in Types]
    ys = [Type[2] for Type in Types]
    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        print(x,y)

getQuakeData()
```

Or, a better way to write that might be:

```
def getQuakeData():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
    # Use with to make sure the file gets closed
    with open(filename, "r") as readfile:
        # no need for readlines; the file is already an iterable of lines
        # also, using generator expressions means no extra copies
        types = (line.split(",") for line in readfile)
        # iterate tuples, instead of two separate iterables, so no need for zip
        xys = ((type[1], type[2]) for type in types)
        for x, y in xys:
            print(x,y)

getQuakeData()
```

---

Finally, you may want to take a look at NumPy and Pandas, libraries which *do* give you a way to implicitly map functionality over a whole array or frame of data almost the same way you were trying to.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `readlines` is a list of strings, each of which is a line of `filename`. Perhaps you meant:

```
for line in readlines:
    Type = line.split(",")
    x = Type[1]
    y = Type[2]
    print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

what i did was a quick fix by converting readlines to string but i do not recommencement it but it works and i dont know if there are limitations or not

```
def getQuakeData():
    filename = input("Please enter the quake file: ")
    readfile = open(filename, "r")
    readlines = str(readfile.readlines())

    Type = readlines.split(",")
    x = Type[1]
    y = Type[2]
    for points in Type:
        print(x,y)
getQuakeData()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got here because you got this (or similar) error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute ...`, then that means you tried to call a method that is not defined on a list object.<sup>1</sup> A very common reason to get this error is that you're inadvertently working on a list object which doesn't define a method you are trying to call on it. Make sure to check for types beforehand.

Some common examples (numpy arrays with non-specified dtype, output of an API call, (unexpected) list of Python objects etc.):

```py
# arr is an array of Python lists without a specific numeric dtype
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5]], dtype=object)
arr[0].mean()                                    # AttributeError


# j is a list of dicts, so cannot call a dict method
j = [{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]
j.get('key1')                                    # AttributeError
```

In many cases, you can simply printing the data type, e.g. `print(type(my_data))` would reveal unexpected input type. Moreover, perhaps use a try-except block to capture the unexpected data type.

---

With that being said, for OP's actual problem, the data seems to be a csv file, so either using the standard `csv` module or `pandas` seem are much cleaner options.

```py
import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in csv.reader(file):
        x, y = line[1], line[2]
        print(x, y)
```

even seeing as the first line seems to the header of the file, we can even use `csv.DictReader`:

```py
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in csv.DictReader(file):
        x, y = line['latitude'], line['longitude']
        print(x, y)
```

Using pandas, it's a single function call.

```py
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

<sup>1</sup> Not counting dunder methods, Python lists define `append`, `clear`, `copy`, `count`, `extend`, `index`, `insert`, `pop`, `remove`, `reverse` and `sort` methods (which you can verify using `dir([])`); `split` is not among them.