# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split' - Python Progject

Tags: python, attributes

Need help with my code, trying to create a music game. I am getting a 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```html
import random

read = open("Songs.txt", "r")
songs = read.readlines()
songlist = []
#readlines - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105507/when-should-i-ever-use-file-read-or-file-readlines
for i in range(len(songs)):
 songlist.append(songs[i].strip('\n'))

songname = random.choice(songlist)
#https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/ - random choice
songs = songs.split()
letters = [word[0] for word in songs]
firstguess = input("Please enter your first guess for the name of the song.")
if firstguess is True:
    print("Well done, you have been awarded 3 points.")
    
elif firstguess is False:
    print("Unlucky, that answer is incorrect. Please try again to win 1 point.")

secondguess = input("Please enter your second guess for the name of the song. Last try, make sure to think before typing!")
if secondguess is True:
    print("Well done, you managed to clutch 1 point.")
elif secondguess is False:
    print("Unlucky, maybe you will know the next song.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer also to this question: [Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042334/attribute-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-split)

From this you can see that `split` is an attribute of strings not lists! The solution from the above question was to split each string/line of the list, so use something like:

```py
songs = [sentence.split() for sentence in songs]
```

To be clear here, `sentence` is an arbitrary iterator and can be named more appropriately (e.g. like verse) for your purpose. Even though it does not matter to the code execution, good naming is always helpful.

Comment: That's great, solved my issue! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, as a new contributor I also like to point out that answers can be marked as solved if you want to indicate a solved problem. You should only do this if you really need no other solutions/alternatives.