# sort a list based on integer returns wrong sort

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to sort a list that contain in each index an integer and a string. like the one in the example.

I used `sort()` and split but I get always the wrong ordered that I expect

```
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem.split("|")[2]
list = ['|val1: 0|0','|val: 0|80','|val1 0|140','|val1: 0|20','|val1: 0|90']
list.sort(key=takeSecond)
print(list)
```

that returns:

```
['|val1: 0|90','|val: 0|80','|val1: 0|20','|val1: 0|0','|val1 0|140']
```

and I expect to get this:

```
['|val1: 0|140','|val: 0|90','|val1: 0|80','|val1: 20|0','|val1 0|0']
```

Where is my mistake in here?

Comment: what is the expected output in above case?

Comment: i expect the to getthis 
  'value2 :280'
  'value1 :30'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042334/attribute-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = ['|val1: 0|0','|val: 0|80','|val1 0|140','|val1: 0|20','|val1: 0|90']
l.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.rsplit('|')[-1]), reverse=True)
```

This will sort your list based on what you need. and the expected output is:

```
In [18]: l                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[18]: ['|val1 0|140', '|val1: 0|90', '|val: 0|80', '|val1: 0|20', '|val1: 0|0']
```

In addition note that:

> Do not use `list` as a variable name. list is a built-in name in python, you will override its functionality .