# Don't understand cause of this AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

I just started learning to program with Python for private interest and I am following a on-line bootcamp. I am supposed to solve some exercises and I started very soon to find the firse difficulties. So, I have this list:

```
chaos =["old price: 40", "new price: 21", "old price: 29", "old price: 50", "new price: 101"]
```

and I would like to insert the list "chaos" in the variable l in order to split it on the colon, so I typed:

```
l = chaos.split(":")

print(l)
```

and, as follows, the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-31400247da2e> in <module>
      1 chaos =["old price: 40", "new price: 21", "old price: 29", "old price: 50", "new price: 101"]
      2 
----> 3 l = chaos.split(":")
      4 
      5 print(l)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I wrote and rewrote it after looking other examples and tutorials but I don´t really understand what I am doing wrong. Can somone help me?

Comment: You have to call `split` on each element of the list, not the list itself. `split` is a method of a string.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042334/attribute-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kederrac's answer is correct. Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension as such:

```py
l = [value for entry in chaos for value in entry.split(':')]
```

Which gives the output:

```
['old price', ' 40', 'new price', ' 21', 'old price', ' 29', 'old price', ' 50', 'new price', ' 101']
```

Looking at the actual cause of the error, the message explains exactly what has happened. A list object, in this case `chaos`, does not have access to the `split` method. That is a reserved method for strings

Furthermore, if you want to keep the list of elements from the split, you can simplify the comprehension to just the following, as suggested by boechat107.

```py
l = [entry.split(':') for entry in chaos]
```

which would result in:

```py
[['old price', ' 40'], ['new price', ' 21'], ['old price', ' 29'], ['old price', ' 50'], ['new price', ' 101']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much both! :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to split each element from the list `chaos`, you could use a `for` loop:

```
l = []

for c in chaos:
    l.extend(c.split(':'))
l
```

output:

```
['old price',
 ' 40',
 'new price',
 ' 21',
 'old price',
 ' 29',
 'old price',
 ' 50',
 'new price',
 ' 101']
```

you can read more about `str.split` [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: I would suggest using list comprehensions: `print([c.split(':') for c in chaos])`.

Comment: @boechat107 worth noting this will print a list of lists, not unpacking the values from the split

Comment: @DragosDumitrache, you're completely right. In the question, it is not clear what is the expected output. My point was to suggest the list comprehension

Comment: Yep, I've included it in my answer so it's more comprehensive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is an exclusive string´s method. Test the command `type(chaos)` and you will check it out.

To solve your problem, as said in some answers and comments above, you need to iterate through the elements of the `chaos` list.

You can use the list compreension `[element.split(":") for element in chao]` or a `for` loop instead:

```
l = []
for element in chaos:
    l.append(element.split(":"))
```